# how can I print out a return value from a function?

Tags: c++, function

so I made a function which returns a value but how would I be able to print that return value to main? p.s. sorry if my formatting is weird im new here.

```
int main()
{
        if (options == 3)
        {
            (powerCalculation(base, exponent));

            //cout << powerCalculation(result) << endl;
            //I want to put the result here
            
        }
    return 0;
}

int powerCalculation(int base, int exponent)
{
    int i = 0;

    int result = base;

    while (i <= exponent)
    {
        result = result * base;

        i++;
    }

    return result;
}
```

Comment: You should just be able to call the method like you would anywhere else.

Comment: what's wrong with the code you've commented out?

Comment: change `//cout << powerCalculation(result) << endl;` into `cout << powerCalculation(2,10) << endl;`

Comment: This doesn’t address the question, but the code in `powerCalculation` has an off-by-two error. Look at what it does when `exponent` is 0 and when it’s 1.

Answer (score 1):

There are two possibilities in main.

1. Save the result in main:

```cpp
     int result = powerCalculation(base, exponent);
     std::cout << result << std::endl;
```

2. Print the result directly without storing it

```cpp
    std::cout << powerCalculation(base, exponent) << std::endl;
```

Answer (score 1):

##### solution

You can directly use the function's return value when calling the function. i.e. `cout << powerCalculation(2,10) << endl;` or `int my_result = powerCalculation(base,exponent);`

##### demo

```cpp
int main(){
    int base=2, exponent=10
    cout << powerCalculation(base, exponent) << endl;
    return 0;
}

int powerCalculation(int base, int exponent){
    int i = 0;
    int result = base;
    while (i <= exponent) {
        result = result * base;
        i++;
    }
    return result;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

```
int powerCalculation(int base, int exponent)
{
    int i = 0;

    int result = base;

    while (i <= exponent)
    {
        result = result * base;

        i++;
    }
    
    // Add this
    cout << result << endl;

    return result;
}
```

Comment: Returning arbitrarily values from `main` (`return calculation;`) is not portable. The only portable return values for `main` are `EXIT_SUCCESS`, `EXIT_FAILURE`, and 0 (which is equivalent to `EXIT_SUCCESS`).

Comment: Whoa, you took out too much. In general, a function that does a calculation shouldn’t print the result. That’s up to the caller. Your original `main` was a reasonable answer, aside from the `return calculation;`.